# Lua iterator to array

Tags: lua

In Lua parlance, is there any syntactic sugar for turning an iterator function into an array (repeated invocations with results stored in ascending indices), perhaps something in the standard library ?

I'm tokenizing a string belonging to a protocol and need to to have positional access to elements at the start of the string, and the end of the string is a variant collection.

The code (specific to my use-case) is as follows, I find it hard to believe that it isn't in the standard library :d

```
local array_tokenise = function (line)
    local i = 1;
    local array = {};

    for item in string.gmatch(line,"%w+") do
      array[i] = item;
      i = i +1
    end

    return array
  end
```

Answer (score 14):

There's no standard library function for it. But really, it's pretty trivial to write:

```
function BuildArray(...)
  local arr = {}
  for v in ... do
    arr[#arr + 1] = v
  end
  return arr
end

local myArr = BuildArray(<iterator function call>)
```

This will *only* work if your iterator function returns single elements. If it returns multiple elements, you'd have to do something different.

Comment: The important line could also be written as `table.insert(arr, v)`, which may be slightly more readable depending on your preferences. Not sure about performance implications though.

Comment: :( moooo, guess I'll have to do with nutrasweet , thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KevinBallard, it would hurt performance very badly. In fact, the most efficient way to do this would be by incrementing an index variable `i`-- still one addition operation per iteration, but no `#` operation.

Comment: @MaxE.: Do you have proof of that? Tables in lua are implemented as hybrids of arrays and hash tables, so if you have an actual integral array, then it's implemented as an array internally. I would expect (though I have no proof) that the `#` operator is constant-time on this sort of table.

Comment: @KevinBallard http://trac.caspring.org/wiki/LuaPerformance a[#a+1] = x executes in 223% of the time as a[i] = x; i = i+1 (0.453 vs 0.203 seconds for a million iterations.) For comparison, table.insert (a, x) executes in 1.25 seconds, which is a major performance hit.

Comment: @MaxE. Huh, color me surprised. I would have expected it to be a bit better-optimized than that. Though you're not quite right, in my tests using `table.insert()` is only slightly slower than using `a[#a+1]` (250ms for `table.insert()` vs 200ms for `a[#a+1]`).

Comment: @KevinBallard Hmm, I should probably redo those tests myself-- Lua may have been optimized better since those tests were conducted.

Comment: @MaxE.: I was testing with Lua 5.1.4 on OS X, using the code from your link.

Comment: @KevinBallard My results, using 1 million iterations, Lua 5.1.4, on Linux with a Core i5 at 2.53 ghz: http://pastebin.com/QSu099ri At 10 million iterations: http://pastebin.com/yMbABu5m At 50 million iterations: http://pastebin.com/Vw9ivVXW Which seems to confirm your results.

Comment: Hi, out of curious I thought there might be some built-in one liner to do this. (I don't care about the performance like ^these crazy guys, I only want to perform operations on small data...)

Answer (score 1):

As Nicol Bolas said, there is no standard library function that performs the action you desire.

Here is a utility function that extends the `table` library:

```
function table.build(build_fn, iterator_fn, state, ...)
    build_fn = (
            build_fn
        or  function(arg)
                return arg
            end
    )
    local res, res_i = {}, 1
    local vars = {...}
    while true do
        vars = {iterator_fn(state, vars[1])}
        if vars[1] == nil then break end
        --build_fn(unpack(vars)) -- see https://web.archive.org/web/20120708033619/http://trac.caspring.org/wiki/LuaPerformance : TEST 3
        res[res_i] = build_fn(vars)
        res_i = res_i+1
    end
    return res
end
```

Here is some example code demonstrating usage:

```
require"stringify"

local t1 = {4, 5, 6, {"crazy cake!"}}
local t2 = {a = "x", b = "y", c = "z"}
print(stringify(table.build(nil, pairs(t1))))
print(stringify(table.build(nil, pairs(t2))))
print(stringify(table.build(
        function(arg) -- arg[1] = k, arg[2] = v
            return tostring(arg[1]).." = "..tostring(arg[2])
        end
    ,   pairs(t1)
)))

local poetry = [[
    Roses are red, violets are blue.
    I like trains, and so do you!
    
    By the way, oranges are orange.
    Also! Geez, I almost forgot...
    Lemons are yellow.
]]
print(stringify(table.build(
        function(arg) -- arg[1] == plant, arg[2] == colour
            return (
                    string.upper(string.sub(arg[1], 1, 1))..string.lower(string.sub(arg[1], 2))
                ..  " is "
                ..  string.upper(arg[2]).."!"
            )
        end
    ,   string.gmatch(poetry, "(%a+)s are (%a+)")
)))
```

Output:

```
{
    [1] = {
        [1] = 1,
        [2] = 4,
    },
    [2] = {
        [1] = 2,
        [2] = 5,
    },
    [3] = {
        [1] = 3,
        [2] = 6,
    },
    [4] = {
        [1] = 4,
        [2] = {
            [1] = "crazy cake!",
        },
    },
}
{
    [1] = {
        [1] = "a",
        [2] = "x",
    },
    [2] = {
        [1] = "c",
        [2] = "z",
    },
    [3] = {
        [1] = "b",
        [2] = "y",
    },
}
{
    [1] = "1 = 4",
    [2] = "2 = 5",
    [3] = "3 = 6",
    [4] = "4 = table: 00450BE8",
}
{
    [1] = "Rose is RED!",
    [2] = "Violet is BLUE!",
    [3] = "Orange is ORANGE!",
    [4] = "Lemon is YELLOW!",
}
```

`stringify.lua` can be found [here](http://codepad.org/NyeoGxQQ)

Answer (score 1):

if you are just looking to auto-increment the table key for each data element, you can use table.insert(collection, item) - this will append the item to the collection and sets the key to the collection count + 1