# I need to split string from a character

Tags: lua, love2d

My string is

```
text1,text2
```

I want to split text1 and text2 by using the ','.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an iterator with the substrings, you can call [string.gmatch](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch).

```
for i in string.gmatch(example, "%P+") do
  print(i)
end
```

To just get them into two separate strings, you can just call the iterator;

```
> iter = string.gmatch(indata, "%P+")
> str1 = iter()
> str2 = iter()
> print (str1)
test1
> print (str2)
test2
```

If you want them stored in an array instead, there's a whole discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316251/lua-iterator-to-array) how to achieve that.

@lhf added a better pattern `[^,]+` in the comments, mine splits on any punctuation, his only on comma.

Comment: And can I put the 'text1' and the 'text2' two strings ?

Comment: Better use `"[^,]+"` in case one of the fields has punctuation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
s="text1,text2"
t1,t2=s:match("(.-),(.-)$")
print(t1,t2)
```

Comment: Fascinating, every time I answer a lua question with what I know, I learn something new from the other answers :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try the functions given in this page:

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin